# "Small" simplicial group equivalent to the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $G$ be a topological group, call $\mathcal{H}\in sGrp$ *simplicial model* of $G$ if there is a homomorphism of topological groups $|\mathcal{H}|\to G$ which is also a homotopy equivalence. In a perfect world, this map would be a homeomorphism, but it does not seem possible since $\mathcal{H}$ should be a Kan complex and hence $|\mathcal{H}|$ should be insanely large.

First, does this definition make sense? If I am not mistaken for any topological group $G$ we can make $S(G)$ into such a model using structure maps of $G$ and an isomorphism $S(G)\times S(G)\cong S(G\times G).$

Second, is there a way to obtain a manageable simplicial model of $S^1$ as a Lie group? Of course, it seems that we can take $S(S^1),$ but is there a way to make it with a countable number of simplices? For example, can we give the Kan complex $\operatorname{Ex}^\infty \mathscr{S}^1$ some kind of group structure making it a simplicial model for $S^1$? Here $\mathscr{S}^1=\Delta^1/\partial\Delta^1$ is the minimal simplicial circle.

Third, is there a way to make things better, if we work with semi-simplicial groups instead? For example, is it true that each Lie group $G$ admits a triangulation that gives rise to a semi-simplicial group $\mathcal{H}$ such that $|\mathcal{H}|\cong_{homeo} G?$

Comment: S^1 is K(Z,1) and therefore is the loop space of K(Z, 2). So taking some simplicial model for K(Z, 2) the (free) group structure on its Kan loop space should give you what you want.

Comment: Two comments: (1) $B\mathbb{Z}$ is another (admittedly still rather large, but smaller than $\operatorname{Sing}(S^1))$ model of $S^1$ as a simplicial group. (2) Consider the simplicial model of the circle with just two non-degenerate simplices (one in dimension $0$, one in dimension $1$).  While this is not a simplicial group, it is a *crossed simplicial group*, which is good enough for some purposes.